# Is there any way to prevent ansible changing my JSON stored in a variable?

Tags: json, ansible

*Edit*: As suggested by Vladimir Botka here is a [minimal example](https://github.com/jeromewaibel/ansible-issue).

I have this template file json.j2

```
{"foo":"{{ var }}"}
```

which I would like to render into a variable and insert that variable into another template

```
- name render it
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: another.j2
    [...]
  vars:
    json_from_template: "{{ lookup('template', 'json.j2') }}"
```

As it seems ansible interprets the json from json.j2 and changes it to

```
{ 'foo': 'var_value' }
```

But "because of reasons" I need the json unchanged, no spaces, no single quotes, as specified in the json.j2.

Can I tell ansible to keep the result of json.j2 as a raw string?

I already tried `!unsafe`, but this

```
  vars:
    json_from_template: !unsafe "{{ lookup('template', 'json.j2') }}"
```

only renders the raw lookup command without any templating at all, and this

```
  vars:
    json_from_template: "{{ !unsafe lookup('template', 'json.j2') }}"
```

does not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: In the snippets below, the callback *yaml* is used to display the output to the screen.

```sh
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK
DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK(/home/admin/.ansible.cfg) = yaml
```

---

Ansible, when templating Jinja2, [tries and converts strings that look like python data structures to python data structures](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/4BES7nRDoCQ). For example

```yaml
shell> cat json.j2 
{"foo":"{{ var }}"}
```

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        json_from_template: "{{ lookup('template', 'json.j2') }}"
      vars:
        var: var_value
    - debug:
        var: json_from_template
    - debug:
        var: json_from_template|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
  json_from_template:
    foo: var_value

  json_from_template|type_debug: dict
```

You can see the type of the variable *json_from_template* is the dictionary. What you need is a string. You have to explicitly declare it

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        json_from_template: "{{ lookup('template', 'json.j2')|string }}"
      vars:
        var: var_value
    - debug:
        var: json_from_template|string
    - debug:
        var: json_from_template|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
  json_from_template|string: |-
    {"foo":"var_value"}

  json_from_template|type_debug: str
```

---

It seems that this ["magic"](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/4BES7nRDoCQ/m/v0dH-y1PAwAJ) conversion works for valid JSON only. See the variable *test_2* below. Other variables remain strings despite the fact that they are valid YAML dictionaries

```yaml
  vars:
    val1: foo
    test1: |-
      {"key1": "foo"}
    test2: |-
      {"key1": "{{ val1 }}"}
    test3: |-
      {"key1": {{ val1 }}}
    test4: |-
      {key1: {{ val1 }}}
    test5: |-
      key1: {{ val1 }}

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          test1: {{ test1|type_debug }}
          test2: {{ test2|type_debug }}
          test3: {{ test3|type_debug }}
          test4: {{ test4|type_debug }}
          test5: {{ test5|type_debug }}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          test1|from_yaml: {{ test1|from_yaml|type_debug }}
          test3|from_yaml: {{ test3|from_yaml|type_debug }}
          test4|from_yaml: {{ test4|from_yaml|type_debug }}
          test5|from_yaml: {{ test5|from_yaml|type_debug }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    test1: AnsibleUnicode
    test2: dict
    test3: str
    test4: str
    test5: str

  msg: |-
    test1|from_yaml: dict
    test3|from_yaml: dict
    test4|from_yaml: dict
    test5|from_yaml: dict
```

---

The "magic" conversion applies to Jinja2 templates in Ansible expressions only. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json_from_template|string }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json_from_template }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    {"foo":"var_value"}

  msg:
    foo: var_value
```

Jinja2 templates inside the [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-builtin-template-template-a-file-out-to-a-target-host) module evaluate always to strings. For example

```yaml
shell> cat another.j2 
{{ json_from_template|string }}
{{ json_from_template }}
```

```yaml
    - template:
        src: another.j2
        dest: output.txt
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat output.txt 
{"foo":"var_value"}

{"foo":"var_value"}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. While I do get "json_from_template|type_debug": "str" the value itself is "json_from_template|string": "{'foo': 'var_value'}" (still with spaces and single quotes). Which version of ansible did you use? Mine is core 2.11.6

Comment: I get the same results for 2.12.1 (python 3.8.5) and 2.10.11 (python 3.6.9). Be careful, 1) the conversion takes place anytime you put a valid JSON string into Jinja2 template 2) What you see on the screen, printed by the debug module, depends on the callback plugin. Minimize your question and make it [mre]. Add expected result.

Comment: I have made an example here: https://github.com/jeromewaibel/ansible-issue

Comment: Inside the template module, the Jinja2 templates are always evaluated to strings. I added an example. Callback *yaml* is used to display the output to the screen.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Does this mean my example is working out-of-the-box as intended for you? Because for me, it still generates wrong JSON in the output.txt (spaces, single-quote).

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/vbotka/7d5e5191ea907099f35af188f8e95465) is the code.

Comment: Incredible. This also produces wrong json for me, both lines.

Comment: OK, I got angry and did a complete uninstall and install of ansible (which upgraded me to core 2.12.1) and now it is working, your example as well as mine. So it seems I actually did hit a bug in ansible. What a bummer.